# How do you make a .com address into just a string in an email?

Tags: html, email

MY code creates an email that has the text `<h1>google.com</h1>` in the body of the email.  When I take a look at the email that is sent, it shows `google.com` as a link.  Is there a way to tag it as not a link but just text via html?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds as though you are unaware of this, but this is actually not a programming-related question. This is something your email client does. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=how+to+turn+off+automatic+links+in+email) or migration to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) (which would be a more suitable Q&A site for this question) will move you in the right direction.

Comment: IMO this is a programming question.  I am the programmer that is creating the template for these emails and I need to be able to program that specific text into a non-link.

Comment: This is something you as the programmer is not responsible for. This is the user's (client's) responsibility. While @Anthony provides a valid solution, he is also right in that you should leave it up to the user.

Comment: @TylerCrompton - On first read, I felt the same way, that it was too software/preferences oriented, but the OP is asking how to create output that meets a specification. It's just not a question that has a true answer, since the OP has no control over the receiving client and perhaps should worry more about the quality of the content rather than how it looks to the recipient.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost always done by the client and will be dependent on on how the client decides what is and is not test.  Similar issues occur with emails that with text such as "please discuss with jessica@accounting" where it's parsed as an email address.

The typical solution is to use html entities for text that shouldn't get parsed by the client. Using your example:

```
 <h1>google&#46;com</h1>
```

I would, however, consider the idea that if something is actually a URL, whether you intended it to be a hyperlink or not, letting the client do what it does, as the user may be accustomed to this feature and like clicking on any url in the body to open it.

Answer (score 0):

If its really an issue, you could always make it an image. i.e Make gif/jpeg with the string "google.com"